# popup window not showing in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup

Hi in the below code I was implemented popup window without onclicklistner in my fragement.Moving from activity to fragment want to show popup but popup window is not showing .

Can any one help me where I did the mistake

Activity.java:

```
Fragment fragment = new HomeNurseFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("myHospitalList", myList);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        loadFragment(fragment);
```

HomeFragment.java:

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_hospitallist, null);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_hospitallist, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    Button save = popupView.findViewById(R.id.save);
                    Button cancel = popupView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                    Button close = popupView.findViewById(R.id.close);
                    MaterialSpinner hospital = customView.findViewById(R.id.hospital);
                    hospital.setHint(Html.fromHtml(hospital.getHint() + " " + "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "* " + "</font>"));
                    hospital.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                    popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
                    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
                            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(customView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                }
```